# Ability to play YouTube videos in webview?

Tags: android, flash, webview, youtube-api, webclient

I want to use flash to play a YouTube video in a webview.

For example, when the WebView loads youtube.com and you click on a video, it will play it fully without any limitations. Currently I get a grey video with a broken flash player picture.

I've tried to add:

```
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState( WebSettings.PluginState.ON );
```

I've also added `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` to the Manifest XML without any luck.

I'm running this on my Nexus 7, don't know if this makes a difference. I've checked every nook and cranny of the internet and haven't found a solution.

```
WebView mWebView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new ClientOP());
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState( WebSettings.PluginState.ON );
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com");
    mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    mWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
}

public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

private class ClientOP extends WebViewClient {

    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        System.out.println("URL: " + url);
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android doesn't support flash anymore. Why don't you use the new Youtube api? 
https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/